# Cannot connect mongodb atlas database in my Ubuntu 22.04 using compass. Connection timeout

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, ip, pymongo, mongodb-atlas

I had created a shared cluster in my atlas account and tried to connect the database using compass with connection string: `mongodb+srv://plutoze:<password>@sample.3a5djse.mongodb.net/test` but it throws me an error after trying to connect for long time with: `queryTxt ETIMEOUT sample.3a5djse.mongodb.net`.
I am using Kubuntu 22.04 and have mongodb installed following this [guide](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/).

I tried to connect with the other two methods

1. Using mongosh (`version=1.8.0`) using the connection string: `mongosh "mongodb+srv://cluster0.ahu3w2i.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase" --apiVersion 1 --username plutoze
2. using pymongo (`version=4.3.3`) on my virtual environment with python=3.10.6

```
import pymongo
client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://adityaawati:<password>@sample.3a5djse.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
db = client.test
```

and I get the following error

```
pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError: The resolution lifetime expired after 21.122 seconds: Server 127.0.0.53 UDP port 53 answered The DNS operation timed out.; Server 127.0.0.53 UDP port 53 answered The DNS operation timed out.; Server 127.0.0.53 UDP port 53 answered The DNS operation timed out.; Server 127.0.0.53 UDP port 53 answered The DNS operation timed out.; Server 127.0.0.53 UDP port 53 answered The DNS operation timed out.; Server 127.0.0.53 UDP port 53 answered The DNS operation timed out.; Server 127.0.0.53 UDP port 53 answered The DNS operation timed out.
I have disabled my firewall too.
```

I'll add some useful information here

```
$ ip a | grep net
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
    inet 192.168.0.106/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp2s0
    inet6 fe80::5a07:18e3:2277:db0a/64 scope link noprefixroute 
    inet 192.168.0.109/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp3s0
    inet6 fe80::3855:cdbd:af72:5c4e/64 scope link noprefixroute
```

mongod.conf file:

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
#  engine:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
  bindIpAll: true

# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

#security:
```

I am stuck trying to connect from past many hours. Please help.

Comment: in your cluster, did you already whitelist your ip address inside?

Comment: I think you mix up something. Mongo Atlas is the MongoDB **Cloud service**, there is no `mongod.conf` file you could define or use. Config file `mongod.conf` is used when you run your MongoDB locally on your own premises.

Comment: yes I had whitelisted my IP. i used connectTimeoutMS too but nothing helped.

Comment: Luckily, i found a work around using the connection string of older mongodb shell and same for python which has the shard cluster stated in replica set. I still don't know why is it not connecting with cluster name. Thanks again for the help.